# More efficient function for this?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with >100 million rows. I need to subset out the rows that carry a particular character (regex), but it's taking a long time because it reads the input row by row. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

A example of the data and the function. Thanks!

```
search_name = function(name) {
      tf = apply(X = hpot["NAME"], 
                 MARGIN = 1, 
                 FUN = grepl, 
                 pattern = name)
      df = hpot[tf == TRUE, ]
      return(df)
}

hpot = data.frame(NAME = c("alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta", "alpha2",
                           "beta3", "gamma4", "zeta"),
                  AGE = c(12, 23, 34, 45, 56, 67, 78, 89),
                  HEIGHT = c(123, 134, 145, 156, 167, 178, 189, 190),
                  HOUSE = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

>search_name("beta")
   NAME AGE HEIGHT HOUSE
2  beta  23    134     B
6 beta3  67    178     B
```

Comment: Do you want to search all columns or just for a match in a certain column?

Comment: @Dason A certain column, I actually hard-coded it into the `search_name`.

Comment: Something like `hpot[grepl("beta", hpot$NAME, fixed=TRUE),]` should be faster for searching through a single column.

Comment: `fixed = TRUE` is key if the letter you're looking for is _fixed_

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @lmo!

```
search_name = function(name) {
      return(hpot[grepl(name, hpot$NAME, fixed = TRUE), ])
}

> search_name("beta")
   NAME AGE HEIGHT HOUSE
2  beta  23    134     B
6 beta3  67    178     B

> search_name("alpha")
    NAME AGE HEIGHT HOUSE
1  alpha  12    123     A
5 alpha2  56    167     A
```

Comment: You could generalize this by having the function take both the dataset and the input column name as inputs instead of hard coding them.